# Cocoapod License in Xcode

Tags: cocoapods

I use Reachability Swift cocoa pod in my project, which is completely free in use and distribute. Should I separately specify the license of the cocoa pod in Xcode, or is it done with the installation of the cocoa pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CocoaPods provides tools to review the license of pods, but nothing further with regards to managing or complying with licenses - that's up to you.

Without being an expert:

- Apache2.0 and MIT licenses are non-restrictive. Apache 2.0 is inspired by MIT, but uses more stringent legal jargon.
- The GNU license specifies that you redistribute the source code. This is tricky, as the app store provides no mechanism for this. Generally avoided for iOS apps.
- Some licenses require attribution in your app's documentation.

To complicate things, there are numerous versions of the Reachability pod, all seem to be inspired by each other, and have different licenses.

Don't take this as legal advice, but probably nobody is looking or cares anyway.

Comment: Thank you Jasper, I was just thinking if using third party frameworks in Xcode, and lastly commit the app to App Store, the last one verify and ask for the licenses!